# How do I return the Username (WP) from this snippet?

Tags: wordpress

Below is a snippet I extracted from one plugin (which I believe lets you get the post's author's display name), and then pasted it into another plugin's functions.php file so that I can have that feature. So now elsewhere in this plugin, how would I go about returning it? For starters, I assume I don't need the 'class userShortcodes' part?

```
class userShortcodes {
    function user_shortcode($atts, $content){   
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) return;
         $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
         return $current_user->user_login;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code i guess you can get username just updating your code.

```
function user_shortcode(){   
        if (!is_user_logged_in()){break;}
        else if(is_user_logged_in()){ 
         $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
         echo $current_user->user_login;
       }    
  }
add_shortcode('ushort','user_shortcode');
```